# How to preserve formatting from NumericUpDown to String

Tags: vb.net, formatting

My form contains several `NumericUpDown` controls. These controls show different amount of decimal places. 
Later in my code I put the different `NumericUpDown.Value`'s in a string array `arrStr()` like so:

```
arrStr(1) = NumericUpDown1.Value
arrStr(2) = NumericUpDown2.Value
arrStr(3) = NumericUpDown3.Value
```

Then I print the array with the `File.WriteAllLines` function to a text file. 
If for example `NumericUpDown1.Value = 1.00`, `NumericUpDown2.Value = 2.30` and `NumericUpDown3.Value = 2.124` the file has the following values in it:

```
1
2.3
2.124
```

I would like to see:

```
1.00
2.30
2.124
```

I have tried `Format` which works, but that formatting method is not convenient as the amount of decimal places is already set for each `NumericUpDown`. It would be annoying to do the work again, but now with `Format`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`String.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx) to force two decimal places:

```
Dim value As Double = 2.3
Dim formatted = String.Format("{0:f2}", value) ' 2.30 '
```

[Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)

**Edit**: If you're array is large and you want to avoid:

`arrStr(1) = String.Format("{0:f2}", NumericUpDown1.Value)` up to `arrStr(86) = String.Format("{0:f2}", NumericUpDown86.Value)`

You can use LINQ to create the array. Assuming that your `NumericUpDown` controls are all in a `GroupBox` called `NumericGroupBox`. You can "inject" the correct number of decimal places:

```
Dim arrStr() As String =
        (From n In NumericGroupBox.Controls.OfType(Of NumericUpDown)()
        Select String.Format("{0:f" & n.DecimalPlaces & "}", n.Value)).ToArray()
```

and here's a version that searches all `TabPages` of your `TabControl`(as commented):

```
Dim allNumerics = From tp In Me.TabControl1.TabPages.Cast(Of TabPage)()
                  From n In tp.Controls.OfType(Of NumericUpDown)()
                  Select String.Format("{0:f" & n.DecimalPlaces & "}", n.Value)
Dim arrStr As String() = allNumerics.ToArray()
```

Comment: The number of decimal places could also be referenced from the NUD control directly, as it was different for different controls.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter: Does that mean I have to do a `String.Format` for each string in the array? If so, that would be the same as using `Format` and would mean I have to do the formatting work all over again for each entry of the array and I would like to avoid that work.

Comment: @BartArondson: You're putting all values into your string array anyway, why couldn't you then use f.e. `arrStr(2) = String.Format("{0:f2}", NumericUpDown2.Value)`?

Comment: Because in my project I have an array with 86 entries and I would like to avoid to enter `arrStr(1) = String.Format("{0:f2}", NumericUpDown1.Value)` up to `arrStr(86) = String.Format("{0:f2}", NumericUpDown86.Value)` if I could somehow get the string formatted depending on the decimal places property of `NumericUpDown`.

Comment: arrStr(1) = String.Format("{0:f" & NumericUpDown1.DecimalPlaces.ToString() & "}", NumericUpDown1.Value)

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Thank you for the effort, your edited answer works well in my example provided in the question. Unfortunately my real code is not structured that well and the `NumericUpDown`'s have more descriptive names like "Turbulence", "Velocity" and "Distance". I was hoping for some default setting that would copy the formatting from all `NumericUpDown` together with the value, but that's probably not possible.

Comment: @BartArondson: I'm not sure if you've tried the LINQ approach in your real code. It's not dependend on the names of the controls but of the type([`Enumerable.TypeOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx)). `NumericGroupBox.Controls.OfType(Of NumericUpDown)()` returns all `NumericUpDown` controls in a specified container.

Comment: @BartArondson: Why did you unaccept the answer, have you any problems?

Comment: @TimSchmelter: I did try it. It works if I put my controls in a Groupbox. But as I have my NumericUpDown controls spread out over different tabs this is not the case. Furthermore I saw that it still depends on one format setting (i.e. `{o:f2}`) and not on the actual amount of decimal places of the relevant `NumericUpDown`. Because of the latter I unmarked your answer as a solution.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Thanks, it works great. I actually found out when a `NumericUpDown` transfers its formatting to a string and when it doesn't. If one fills in "1.00" or just selects the number before the dot and replaces it, the `NumericUpDown` copies its formatting to the string. When one just selects the whole value, replaces it with "1" and let the control add the trailing dot and the zeros then the string will only contain "1" and not "1.00"